# Why is my insert into std::map failing?

Tags: c++

In my header file, I'm declaring a map like so:

```
std::map<LPD3DXSPRITE, LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9> sprites;
```

In my C++ file, I am trying to insert like so:

```
sprites.insert(sprite, texture);
```

The types I am passing to sprites.insert are correct.  Why can I not insert this way?  What is the proper way to insert?  When I do this, the error I get is like this (snipped):

> error C2664:
>   'std::_Tree<_Traits>::iterator
>   std::_Tree<_Traits>::insert(std::_Tree<_Traits>::iterator,const
>   std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : cannot
>   convert parameter 1 from
>   'LPD3DXSPRITE' to
>   'std::_Tree<_Traits>::iterator'

Comment: What are the declared types of `sprite` and `texture` ?

Comment: "The types I am passing to sprites.insert are correct" ORLY? ;-)

Comment: @Steve the types matched the types I'd assigned in my map :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to wrap your key and value in an `std::pair` object:

```
sprites.insert(std::make_pair(sprite, texture));
```

This is because `std::map` is a [Pair Associative Container](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/PairAssociativeContainer.html).  The `value_type` of `std::map<K,V>` is `std::pair<const K,V>`.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you could use `operator[]`. For std::map, this will [autovivify](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/operator[]/) for you. Depending on what you are doing, it may make calling std::map::insert unnecessary.

Comment: `insert` will check if the value already exists in `map`, `operator[]` sets the value for key without checking so it depends on what functionality you need